# How is a page instance's slug defined in Mezzanine CMS?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

From the [Mezzanine docs](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/docs/content-architecture.rst):

> By default the template pages/page.html is used, but if a custom template exists it will be used instead. The check for a custom template will first check for a template with the same name as the Page instance’s slug, and if not then a template with a name derived from the subclass model’s name is checked for. So given the above example the templates pages/dr-seuss.html and pages/author.html would be checked for respectively.

The question is where does Mezzanine CMS gets the slug for an instance of a page? Is it from the title attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slug is automatically generated from the title attribute by default, but it can also be set manually from the "URL" option in the meta data section of the page admin.